# Error creating Swap File. Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, swap, lts

Please be gentle with me, I am a noob and will need simple explanations.

I wanted to increase swap file size, but encountering some weird behavior.

Full story - I had 2G and wanted to allocate more space. First, I followed a suggestion to have double of ram and entered 8G, but then changed my mind and decided to change it to 4G.
BUT after following the same procedure as the first time, it stays 8G still.

I followed [this](https://devanswers.co/creating-swap-space-ubuntu-18-04/) guide

This is what I get (edited to show main points):

```
~$ sudo swapon --show
~$
~$ sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile
~$ ls -lh /swapfile 
-rw------- 1 root root 8.0G Feb 14 12:14 /swapfile
~$ sudo swapon --show
NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file   8G   0B   -2
```

How do I set it to 4G and make sure it's functioning correctly?

Comment: Did you have a previous `/swapfile` that was already 8 GB large? It looks like that. Notice that `fallocate` will not shrink an existing file that is already larger than the size you requested.

Comment: The traditional way to preallocate a file of a given size is with the _dd_ command: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=4` which will allocate _or_ shrink the file to that exact size. _fallocate_ behaves quite surprisingly here.

Comment: thank you! You are right, I changed from 2 to 8 first, and then decided to change it to 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, stop using and delete the old swap file:

```
sudo swapoff /swapfile
sudo rm /swapfile
```

Secondly, create the new swapfile:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=4
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
```

Thirdy, configure the file for use as a swapfile:

```
sudo mkswap /swapfile
```

Finally, utilize the new 4G swapfile:

```
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Please note that you *can but should not* use fallocate to create your swapfile.  Notes in `man swapon` indicate that it should work, if the underlying disk structure is XFS, but that problem may occur otherwise.

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked.

Comment: Is curious how in all the tutorials that I read did not do mention that is not possible resize the `/swapfile` - therefore is mandatory remove and re-create